# rtcwake not working on Ubuntu 14.04 installed on MacBook Air (mid 2012)

Tags: ubuntu, power-management, macintosh, suspend, clock

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 GNU/Linux on a MacBook Air (mid 2012).
I'm trying to use `rtcwake` to implement a "delayed hibernation from suspend", as in https://askubuntu.com/a/33192 (the particular use case is not important here). But `rtcwake`, issued e.g. as,

```
sudo rtcwake --seconds 120  --mode mem
```

enters suspend (`--mode mem`) **only for a few seconds** (regardless of what the `--seconds` option says) and immediately returns. Both suspend and hibernate work correctly on this system, e.g. when triggered by `pm-suspend` or `pm-hibernate` (using the kernel's `swsusp`), or upon closing the lid. The machine keeps the time correctly and can show or update it in Ubuntu.
The same command works as expected on another (non-Apple) machine with a similar GNU/Linux OS.

I know MAC OS X has this kind of feature to wake up from sleep at a preset time or after a preset duration. So, I believe, they are accessing an internal clock. My questions are (all related):

Is there some wake-up event occurring behind the scenes that's triggering this immediate wake-up? I doubt this could be the culprit, since, as I mentioned above, the machine suspends correctly otherwise. (But then again, suspending correctly otherwise could be possibly due to the offending module(s) being removed by a `SUSPEND_MODULES` hook before such "normal" suspend.) Also, the machine does not wake up from a normal suspend, triggered, e.g., by closing the lid, when a scheduled `rtcwake` says it should.

If there aren't any "hidden" wake-up events, how do I use this internal clock to trigger a scheduled wake-up from suspend in GNU/Linux, since `rtcwake` doesn't seem to be working? Is this clock RTC compatible to support standard driver model wakeup flags from a GNU/Linux tool?  Are there any other methods/workarounds to achieve this result?

Comment: Did you try to wake up at given time (`-t` option)?

Comment: Yes, `-t` leads to the same result (wake-up after a second or two) as `-s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the culprit. Doing `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup`, and disabling the `*enabled` devices one by one (using, e.g., `sudo echo 'DEVABBRV' > /proc/acpi/wakeup`, where `DEVABBRV` is the device abbreviation listed in the `cat` output above), it turns out that `LID0` is waking up the machine "prematurely".

This is perhaps due to some non-standard, proprietary hardware sensor in the lid. Disabling the wake-up capability for `LID0` (which could be made permanent by adding `echo 'LID0' > /proc/acpi/wakeup` to `/etc/rc.local`) makes `rtcwake`, and in particular `sudo rtcwake --seconds 120  --mode mem`, function as expected.

However, the problem still remains unsolved for my particular use case (with the script in https://askubuntu.com/a/33192), since `rtcwake` *does not* wake up the machine when run in that script.